# asp.net: refer to a page relative to root in normal non-server-side html controls

Tags: asp.net, url, relative-path, root

I've a page that is deeply nested. And one that is in the root path. Inside of the deeply nested page I have an anchor tag which is supposed to navigate to another page (which is not in the root, but it is easy to specify a root relative path).

I've done the following trying to specify a root relative path:

`<a href="~/home/main.aspx">Home</a>` -> This one gives me a 404 error. It is not able to resolve `~` part to the root path.

The other option is to travel one directory up:

`<a href="../../../home/main.aspx">Home</a>` -> This is headache.

Then I tried this:

`<a href="/home/main.aspx">Home</a>` -> This gave me a 404 again. It simply removed what came after the `localhost:<port_number>/` part and affixed it with `/home/main.aspx`.

What is the way to specify a root relative path here?

PS: I assume the root relative path will resolve for server controls

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A tilde (~) is only recognized by the `WebControl.ResolveUrl` method, so you will have to invoke this method on the `Page`, which is a `WebControl`

```
<a href='<%=ResolveUrl("~/home/main.aspx") %>'>Home</a>
```

Comment: But I also kind of fixed this by making the `Virtual Path` property to `/`. It helped...

Comment: @deo - `/` and `~/` refer to 2 different paths - while they may appear the same in your development environment on your server they may be different. `/` is the absolute root of the server whereas `~/' is the absolute root of the current application. Do you see the difference? You usually only want to use `~/`. Be sure that when you use `/` that you understand where it *will* be pointing.

Comment: You can also set `runat="server"` on an HTML control and ASP.NET will convert the ~/ to the application root.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the asp.net hyperlink control you will be able to use the '~'.  If you don't want to use a servercontrol I think your stuck.

'/' will take you to the root of the site on a regular link but you have to check how you have the virtual directory is set up.